# Ошибка в работе с LinkedList

Tags: java, android

Есть класс:

```
class CurrentMessage
{
    CurrentMessage(String from_login,
                   String from_public_key,
                   String from_enc,
                   String from_signature,
                   String who_login,
                   String who_public_key,
                   String who_enc,
                   String who_signature,
                   String date)
    {
        this.from_login = from_login;
        this.from_public_key = from_public_key;
        this.from_enc = from_enc;
        this.from_signature = from_signature;
        this.who_login = who_login;
        this.who_public_key = who_public_key;
        this.who_enc = who_enc;
        this.who_signature = who_signature;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String from_login;
    public String from_public_key;
    public String from_enc;
    public String from_signature;
    public String who_login;
    public String who_public_key;
    public String who_enc;
    public String who_signature;
    public String date;
}
```

Далее добавляю элемент в список:

```
...
LinkedList<CurrentMessage> message_list;                                 
message_list.addFirst(new CurrentMessage(from_login,
                                         from_open_key,
                                         message_enc_from_key,
                                         signature_from,
                                         who_login,
                                         who_open_key,
                                         message_enc_who_key,
                                         signature_who,
                                         date_time));
Log.d("LIST123", Integer.toString(message_list.size()));
```

При добавлении нового элемента в двунаправленных списков вылетает ошибка:

> ERRORjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void java.util.LinkedList.addFirst(java.lang.Object)' on a null
>   object reference

Что я делаю не так? В Java начинающий.

Comment: вы объявили список, но не создали его. Объявите так `LinkedList<CurrentMessage> message_list =  new LinkedList<>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы не иницировали список message_list. 
вы долны иницировать список перед тем, как начинать добавлять данные. 
Поэтому, нужно писать так

```
LinkedList<CurrentMessage> message_list = new LinkedList();
```

p.s. Не желательно в конструктор передавать много параметров. Посмотрите на [шаблон билдер](http://cpp-reference.ru/patterns/creational-patterns/builder/)